# How can I configure the target namespace globally in JAX-WS web services?

Tags: jax-ws, java-metro-framework, convention-over-configur

I have a lot of endpoints annotated with `@WebService(targetNamespace = "mynamespace")`. Every `@WebResult` and `@WebParam` has the same definition of `targetNamespace = "mynamespace"`.

Is there a way to configure JAX-WS (Metro implementation) to use `"mynamespace"` as targetNamespace by default?

I would like to use the annotations without any attributes and get rid of the duplicate declarations, just like convention over configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Only put the `targetNamespace` in the *service endpoint interface* or *service implementation
bean*.

```java
/**
* Annotated Implementation Object
*/
@WebService(
    name = "CustomerService",
    targetNamespace = "http://org.company.services"
)
public class CustomerService {
    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="CustomerRecord")
    public CustomerRecord locateCustomer(
        @WebParam(name="FirstName") String firstName,
        @WebParam(name="LastName") String lastName,
        @WebParam(name="Address") USAddress addr) {
        ...
    }
};
```

If `@WebResult` or `@WebParam` have no `targetNamespace`, the default is
the `targetNamespace` for
the Web Service.

In another hand, you can avoid the all annotations and only use the `@WebService` if you don't need something custom with JAX-B.

See more in [JSR-181 Web Services Metadata for the JavaTM Platform](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=181)

Comment: When I leave out the `targetNamespace` at `@WebResult` and at `@WebParam` the generated XML in the SOAP response has a namespace for the outermost XML tag (e.g. `<ns0:locateCustomerResponse>`), but the inner ones uses the default namespace (e.g. `<CustomerRecord>`).The same happens to the parameters (`<firstName>` instead of `<ns0:firstName>`).

Comment: One would think the above example would work, but unfortunately it doesn't like tim mentions above. Why is something so simple not easy to achieve? There has to be a way to not constantly copy and paste this namespace on every single WebParam and WebResult annotation.

Comment: It seems the easy way to to this is to rename the java package to match targetNamespace :(